# Proving an inequality using calculus (with FTC and Talyor's Theorem?)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function with $f''\leq 0$. Prove that for any $x \geq 0$,
>   $$ \int_x^{2x}f(t)\, dt \leq xf\bigg(\frac{3}{2} x\bigg)$$

**Attempt**

For each $x \geq 0$, let $g(x)= \int_0^x f(t)\, dt$ and $$h(x) = xf\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)-\int_x^{2x} f(t)\, dt=xf\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)-g(2x)+g(x)$$

The problem boils down to proving that $h(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

I tried to apply Taylor's expansion on $h$ about $0$. But I could not get useful result:

By FTC, $g'(x)=f(x)$. Therefore, by applying chain rule,

$$h'(x)=f\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)+\frac{3x}{2}f'\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)-2f(2x)+f(x)$$

$$h''(x)=3f'\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)+\frac{9x}{4}f''\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x\bigg)-4f'(2x)+f'(x)$$

Now we have $g(0) = h(0) = h'(0) = h''(0)  = 0$. So that for all $x > 0$, there is some $t \in (0,x)$ such that

$$h(x)= h(0)+h'(0)x +\frac{h''(t)}{2}x^2 = \frac{h''(t)}{2}x^2$$

So that $h(x)\geq 0 \iff h(t) \geq 0$. Since $f'' \leq 0$ and $2t > 3t/2 > t$, $f'(2t) \leq f'(3t/2) \leq f'(t)$

$$h''(x)=3f'\bigg(\frac{3}{2}t\bigg)+\frac{9t}{4}f''\bigg(\frac{3}{2}t\bigg)-4f'(2t)+f'(t) \geq \frac{9t}{4} f''\bigg(\frac{3}{2}t\bigg)$$

But $tf''(3t/2)$ can be negative and I don't know what to do now. So is there is better lower bound for $h''(t)$ or have I gone into a wrong direction?

Comment: How come in the yellow quoted part of the question you say $f'' \le 0$; but in the body of the text (after you use MVT) you say $f'' \ge 0$

Comment: If you really do mean that $f'' \ge 0$ in the question then of course you're done!

Comment: That was a typo thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f''(x) \leq 0$ for every $x$, we have that $f$ is a concave function, hence
$$
f(t) \leq f\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right) + \left(t - \frac{3}{2}x\right) f'\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right),
\qquad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
If $x>0$, integrating this inequality on the interval $[x, 2x]$ we get
$$
\int_x^{2x} f(t)\, dt \leq x \, f\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right) +
f'\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right) \int_x^{2x} \left(t - \frac{3}{2}x\right)\, dt
= x \, f\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right).
$$

Comment: All to easy.  (+1)